# How do I find a Subversion user in the settings?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I installed and set up SVN and TortoiseSVN for a project a few months ago. I created a user (User1) that I am logged in as. It all works well. But when I log in as admin in the CollabNet Subversion Edge tool, I do not see User1 in the Users list. I checked the svnserve.conf file as well and there is no User1. I think I created the user using the Subversion Edge tool (I think). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't create the user using Subversion Edge, you should be able to create it with the same user name and password without a problem.  This way it will show up in the admin panel.

When creating users that aren't tied to LDAP, it just verifies that the user name and password match, there is no unique ID associated to a particular way that user was created.

Comment: The user is not tied to LDAP.

Comment: In that case you should be able to recreate the user in Edge with the same user name and password.  It could be that Edge reads the user account list from somewhere special so it's not aware of users that it has not created on its own.